# C# DataSet multiple results

Tags: c#, t-sql, datatable, dataset

I have a stored procedure which returns 5 or 6 results:

```
SELECT 1 .....

SELECT 2 .....

SELECT 3 .....

SELECT 4 .....

SELECT 5 .....
```

Now in C# code I am feeding DataSet within this results.

```
static DataSet GetData()
{
    DataSet ds_Data = new ds_Data();
    IDBManager dbManager = ConnectDB();

    try
    {
        dbManager.Open();
        ds_Data = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure,"sp_GetData");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        dbManager.Close();
        dbManager.Dispose();
    }

    return ds_Data;
}
```

Now I need to give names to each DataTable in DataSet. How can I hanlde when eg. SELECT 2 return no rows (it may happen when other SELECT statements will return no rows)? I need that SELECT 1 will go to Table1Name, SELECT 2 to Table2Name etc.

Comment: Why does it matter if there are no rows?

Comment: ds_Data.Tables[0].TableName = "T1"; ?

Comment: If one of the tables will be empty, C# code returns error that table[i] cannot be found or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue in my code. The DataSet is returned properly even it has no rows. The problem was in LINQ to DataTable. I was incorrectly assigning table names. I decided to name the tables after I downnload data from database. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, from the stored proc, you can't do that.

You can, however, set the names once you have retrieved the DataSet, and then use them from then on.
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "NameofTable1";

Comment: I know that I can't to this from stored procedure. My problem is that I need dynamically set table name. I need to know that in case SELECT 3 return no rows to not give that table Table3Name.

Comment: cant's you write if-else logic to check if the table has rows or not.

Comment: I can miss something but from what I found, in case when eg SELECT returns no rows, C# will treat SELECT 4 as Table3. So this is my problem. I think that when I would like to use if-else logic it would have many lines.